# R Downloading an excel file from HTTPS site with redirect

Tags: r, curl, https, download, rcurl

I want to download a number of excel files from a website. The **website requires a username and password**, but I can log in manually before running the code. After logging in, if I manually copy the url to my browser (chrome) it downloads file for me. But when I do it in R, closest it gives me a text file which looks like HTML code of the same website from which I need to download the file. Also note the URL structure. There is an "occ4.xlsx" in the middle which I believe is the file.

I can also explain the other parameters in url:

- country=JP (country - Japan)
- jloc=state-1808 (state id - it will change with states)
- ...
- ...
- time frame  etc etc

Here is what I have tried:

**Iteration 1 (inbuilt methods):**

```
url <- "https://www.wantedanalytics.com/wa/counts/occ4.xlsx?country=JP&jloc=state-1808&mapview=msa&methodology=available&t%5Bsegment%5D%5Bperiod_prior%5D=count&t%5Bsegment%5D%5Bperiod_timeframe%5D=count&t%5Bsegment%5D%5Bperiod_type%5D=&t%5Bsegment%5D%5Bqty%5D=1000&t%5Btimeframe%5D=f2013-10-17-2017-02-17&timeframe=f2013-09-28-2017-02-17"
url_ns <- "http://www.wantedanalytics.com/wa/counts/occ4.xlsx?country=JP&jloc=state-1808&mapview=msa&methodology=available&t%5Bsegment%5D%5Bperiod_prior%5D=count&t%5Bsegment%5D%5Bperiod_timeframe%5D=count&t%5Bsegment%5D%5Bperiod_type%5D=&t%5Bsegment%5D%5Bqty%5D=1000&t%5Btimeframe%5D=f2013-10-17-2017-02-17&timeframe=f2013-09-28-2017-02-17"
destfile <- "test"
download.file(url, destfile,method="auto")
download.file(url, destfile,method="wininet")
download.file(url, destfile,method="auto", mode="wb")
download.file(url, destfile,method="wininet", mode="wb")
download.file(url_ns, destfile,method="auto")
download.file(url_ns, destfile,method="wininet")
download.file(url_ns, destfile,method="auto", mode="wb")
download.file(url_ns, destfile,method="wininet", mode="wb")
#all of above download the webpage and not the file
```

Iteration 2 (using RCurl):

```
# install.packages("RCurl")
library(RCurl)
library(readxl)
x <- getURL(url)
y <- getURL(url, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
z <- getURL(url, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE, ssl.verifyhost=FALSE)
identical(x,y) #TRUE
identical(y,z) #TRUE
x
[1] "<html><body>You are being <a href=\"http://www....2-17\">redirected</a>.</body></html>"
# **Note the text about redirect**
out <- readxl::read_xlsx(textConnection(x)) # I know it won't work
#Error in read_fun(path = path, sheet = sheet, limits = limits, shim = shim,  : 
                    Expecting a single string value: [type=integer; extent=1].
w = substr(x,36,nchar(x)-31) #removing redirect text
identical(w,url) # FALSE
out <- readxl::read_xlsx(textConnection(w))
#Error in read_fun(path = path, sheet = sheet, limits = limits, shim = shim,  : 
                    Expecting a single string value: [type=integer; extent=1].
download.file(w, destfile,method="auto")
#Downloads the webpage again
download.file(url_ns,destfile,method="libcurl")
#Downloads the webpage again
```

I also tried downloader package but same results!
I can't share username and password on this question, but if you are trying your hands on this problem, do let me know by comment/pm and I will share the same with you!

Comment: The issue is when you are making your request from within R; the sites session-cookie(the thing that keeps you logged in and tells the website you are who you say you are and therefor you can access the files) is not being recognized. To the website, it looks as though someone has directly visited the download page, but without first signing in, which would return an invalid.. or in this case the website's logic is "if user not logged in, redirect". You'll need to authenticate yourself within the http calls from R, by sending your session cookies, or authenticating.

Comment: @CarlBoneri, I tried these but still did not work for me  `x = GET(url, authenticate("gsinghal", "xxxx"))`  and `x2 <- getURL(url_ns, userpwd="gsinghal:xxxx", httpauth = 1L)`. Can you help me here